# pandas groupby & filter on count

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to capture some categorical values with an occurence above a certain threshold:

```
df:
ticket_id,  category,  amount --> some more columns
1020        cat1       1000
1022        cat1       55
1023        cat1       12291
1120        cat2       140
1121        cat3       1250 
^
|
|
Way more rows with mostly (1020) cat5, (98) cat1, cat3, cat4 and no cat2.

>>>> df.groupby('category')['amount'].count()
category
cat1       100
cat2       1
cat3       6
cat4       2
cat5       1020
```

I want to get the categories with count > 20 in a list. Currently I'm doing:

```
>>>> t = test.groupby('disposition')['fine_amount'].agg(['count','mean'])
>>>> t[t['count']>10].index.values
array(['cat1','cat5'])
```

Now this works, but I believe it can be done shorter: In order to refer the `count column` I need  at least 2 aggregate functions, further more I need 1 variables & 2 lines.
I was hoping something like:

```
>>>> groupby('category')['amount'].apply(lambda x: x.count() > 10)
```

but that yields:

```
cat1    100   True
etc

>>>> groupby('category')['amount'].apply(lambda x: x[x.count() > 10])
Fails completely

>>>> groupby('category')['amount'].count().nlargest(2)
gives the correct list but in this case because I know there are 2 elements.
```

What is the most elegant / performing solution?

Comment: Can you post the initial dataframe? Or at least a small sample of it?

Comment: Suggest retitling because the doesn't reflect what was really asked, and the answers don't answer the question in the title.  That means this comes up in searches for the question in the title, but this page does not answer that question.

Comment: @RobertP.Goldman English is not my mothers' tongue but I think title and answers still seems accurate after 2 years. I can imagine that other problems can have the same title but that's SO.Admittedly 6k views with 2 upvotes does not indicate a very sophisticated question. If I see more upvotes to your comment or you have a constructive alternative I'll reconsider the titling.

Comment: @drjerry the problem is that none of the responses answers the question you ask. Of the two answers, both add new columns and indexing, instead using group by and filtering by count.  The best I could come up with was `new_df = new_df.groupby(["col1", "col2"]).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 10_000)` but I don't know if that's a good answer or not.  Counting by using `len` is probably not the best solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make this much cleaner by just using the result of your initial groupby and indexing that:

***Setup***

```
categories = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5']
dct = {'categories': [random.choice(categories) for i in range(75)], 'amount': [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(75)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

**`groupby`** with **`count`**

```
s = df.groupby('categories').amount.count()

# categories
# cat1    12
# cat2    10
# cat3    21
# cat4    17
# cat5    15
# Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Nice and clean indexing:

```
s[s > 20].index.tolist()
['cat3']
```

Comment: Thanks still 2 lines and 1 variable. but the 2 aggregations functions are gone.

Answer (score 6):

You can use lambda express in boolean indexing:

Borrowing from @user2483203 setup:

```
np.random.seed(123)
categories = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5']
dct = {'categories': [np.random.choice(categories) for i in range(100)], 'amount': [np.random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(100)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

Use `value_counts` and boolean indexing:

```
df['categories'].value_counts()[lambda x: x>20].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['cat4', 'cat2']
```